# Ansible: How to use the same condition for multiple pretask

Tags: ansible

Suppose I have multiple pretasks which will be executed base on the same condition:

```
pre_task:
  -name: Task1
   when: condition1
  -name: Task2
   when: condition1
  -name: Task3
   when: condition1
```

How can I rewrite it such that I don't need to repeat the condition for Task1, Task2 and Task3?

Answer (score 3):

## YAML references

This is completely unrelated to Ansible. References and anchors are part of YAML. Once defined as `&foo` it can be re-used as `*foo` in the same YAML document.

```
pre_task:
  - name: Task1
    when: &myCondition condition1
  - name: Task2
    when: *myCondition
  - name: Task3
    when: *myCondition
```

## Blocks

Ansible 2 introduced [blocks](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_blocks.html). With blocks, tasks can be grouped and beside other features a block can take a condition which is applied to all contained tasks.

```
pre_tasks:
  - block:
      - name: Task1
      - name: Task2
      - name: Task3
    when: condition1
```

## Includes

This is more a workaround than a valid solution. Widely used in Ansible 1 since the lack of blocks though. Includes can take conditions and are applied to all contained tasks.

```
- include: otherFile.yml
  when: condition1
```

All tasks then are contained in `otherFile.yml`:

```
- name: Task1
- name: Task2
- name: Task3
```

## Loops

This only will work if your tasks are of the same type and only take different parameters. Let's assume you have 3 template tasks:

```
- name: All 3 tasks
  template:
    src: "{{ item.src }}"
    dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
  when: condition1
  with_items:
    - src: template1.j2
      dest: /some/path/file1
    - src: template2.j2
      dest: /some/path/file2
    - src: template3.j2
      dest: /some/path/file3
```

In a loop, conditions are executed for every single iteration.